# Custom React compartment variable can't be read

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Now I am making some simple compartment of div region box

name as Card

In Card Class I write down like this

```
  render() {
const tagId = this.props.tagId;
const tagTitle = this.props.tagTitle;
const tagColor = this.props.tagColor;
console.log('----------------------', tagColor);
return (
  <div style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}>
    <div
      id={tagId}
      style={{
        height: '20px',
        width: 'auto',
        background: { tagColor },
        margin: '20px 0',
        maxWidth: '100%'
      }}
    >
      { tagTitle }
    </div>
    <div>{this.props.data}</div>
  </div>
);
}
```

but It can't read down the tagColor variable on the style expression

```
background: { tagColor },
```

I found that the variable's value can change. 
but not in the style = { } why?

And How to deal with this stuff ?

Any Ideas?

Comment: you should probably use `backgroundColor: tagColor`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `{}` inside the style tag, you can directly assign the variable

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 
render() {
    const tagId = 'abc';
    const tagTitle = "hello";
    const tagColor = 'red';
    console.log('----------------------', tagColor);
    return (
      <div style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}>
        <div
          id={tagId}
          style={{
            height: '20px',
            width: 'auto',
            background:  tagColor ,
            margin: '20px 0',
            maxWidth: '100%'
          }}
        >
          { tagTitle }
        </div>
        <div>{53253}</div>
      </div>
    );
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```